# Linguistics concept about meaning of words according to a context

Tags: computational-linguistics, cross-linguistic, theoretical-linguistics, meaning

Several linguistics questions about the meaning in context of words:

How is called in linguistics the fact some words have a meaning only with other words?

How is it called when a word changes completely its meaning when another word is in the same sentence, and when it's just next to another word? And when it gains other meanings (that are not always in the dictionary)? And the meaning are the opposite?

A language, in general, has the ability to change words according to the context: Are all languages like this? How this property of the language is called?

Is this property a brake to the use of computer-made speech?

Is there name for all that concepts?

Comment: It's possibly not semantics that you ask of?

Comment: I thinks semantics is broader.

Comment: Yes, semantics and/or pragmatics, etc.; it’s hard to say without any examples given.

Comment: Yes. Examples of the phenomenon are essential. Otherwise it's everybody throwing terminology around in the dark.

Comment: Too many question in one, too vague and broad, and asking for opinions. There is much to be improved on this question ,,,

Comment: @Quidam you might want to edit your question.

Comment: I will try to improve it, but I have no idea for now. If I open a question for each, I don't think it could be well received. So if people tries to reply what they can, it could be interesting. When the question are too precise, sometimes there is no answer.

Comment: "idiomaticity" -- See http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.729.3869&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 3):

> How is called in linguistics the fact some words have a meaning only with other words?

Words that have many context-dependent meanings are called [polysemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysemy). Although their meaning depends usually on much more than just other words in the sentence – it's often affected by [intonation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intonation_(linguistics)), broader context of the sentence, opinions of the speaker and much more. There is also a category of words called [auto-antonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym), which have two opposite meanings that depend on the context. One such word is the verb „[dust](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dust)“, which can mean either „to remove dust“ (eg. dusting shelves) or „to add dust“ (eg. dusting a cake with sugar).

> Is this property a brake to the use of computer-made speech?

It's usually not a big problem in the field of [speech synthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_synthesis) (converting text to speech) as the intonation could be most probably approximated by [neural networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network) [[1]](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0885230815300486) [[2]](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0885230813000041). It will however cause problems in the case of [homographs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homograph) that are pronounced differently, for example „read“ [is pronounced](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/read#Pronunciation) **/ɹiːd/** in present tense and **/ɹɛd/** in past tense and past participle.

However it *is* a problem for [natural language understanding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_understanding) (ie. making computers understand human language), as this dependency on context, together with [metaphors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphor) and [implied meanings](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/374712/literary-term-for-implied-meaning), makes NLU an [AI-hard problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AI-complete). This means that it's generally believed that computers won't understand human speach until they are as inteligent as humans.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! For your first point, I'm looking for a concept more than "polysemy", but changing sometimes radically the meaning (e.g the opposite) or a word that has only a meaning with the context. Context-only meaning. I don't know if there are names for this. I will seach againt and edit my question to be more precise.

Comment: Words that can get the opposite meaning are called "auto-antonyms" and they are already mentioned in my answer . I don't know about any *context-only* words, but I'll think about it and eventually edit my answer.

Comment: Well, I've got a somewhat disappointing answer for the *context-only words*: all [pronouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronoun) are heavily context-dependent. However you were probably looking for nouns, verbs and adjectives, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for a broad term: context-dependency.

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics! Please expand your post, don't give just a single-line answer. A quality post requires explanation and some credible references.

Comment: I don't think it's a linguistics term. More a computational linguistics term?